# How to remove text field value after comma using apex code?

Tags: apex, string

I have text field and that field has these two email address, field value is look like abc@test.com, def@test.com

Now, i need to remove second email address after comma..

i wrote some code to achieve this, can somebody please tell me about the mistake in this code :

```
if(a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c != null){
     List<String> tempstr = String.valueOf(a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c).split(',');
     system.debug('++++tempstr++++++'+tempstr);
     String temp = '';
     for(string str : tempstr){
          if(Str.trim().length() > 0){
          temp = temp+str;
          system.debug('++++temp1++++++'+temp);
     }
     a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c = temp.removeEnd(',');
     system.debug('++++Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c++++++'+a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c);

}
```

Please suggest !!

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you only need the first email value,you don't need any loop.
Just use the code below;

```
if(a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c != null && (a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c).contains(',')){
    a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c = a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c.split(',')[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do as you are already splitting but say you want to remove the second email. If you just need the first, after doing one of the below access the first by `emails[0]`

The easiest way to do this if the emails are separated by commas is to:

```
String em = 'abc@test.com, def@test.com';
String [] emails = em.split(',');
```

If you need to clean up you can do this instead:

```
String em = 'abc@test.com, def@test.com';
String [] emails = New String[]{};

for(String tmp : em.split('.')){
      emails.add(tmp.trim());
}
```

If you are trying to join them back to a string you would do

```
String rejoin = string.join(emails,',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.I added the break in for loop

```
    if(a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c != null){
     List<String> tempstr = String.valueOf(a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c).split(',');
     system.debug('++++tempstr++++++'+tempstr);
     String temp = '';
     for(string str : tempstr){
          if(Str.trim().length() > 0){
          temp = temp+str;
          system.debug('++++temp1++++++'+temp);
          a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c = temp.removeEnd(',');
     }
     break;

     system.debug('++++Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c++++++'+a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c);

}
```

Comment: And i Believe  a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c = temp.removeEnd(','); can be replaced with  a.Temporary_Email_address_coming_from_OTT__c = temp;

Not sure though.PLease check

Comment: only issue was iteration and you help me to stop it. Thanks man !! :)

Comment: Please mark the answer which solved your query so that it can benefit others